# Tools to help detect different uses of ambiguous tags

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

I just discovered that [case-when](/questions/tagged/case-when) was sometimes being used when [switch-statement](/questions/tagged/switch-statement) should be used.

In order to find questions where it was mis-used, I looked for questions tagged with [case-when](/questions/tagged/case-when), and eliminated questions with other tags indicating that it was used correctly (generally SQL related). I ended up with a query of

```
[case-when] -[sql] -[tsql] -[sql-server] -[hql] -[mysql] -[oracle] -[sql-server-2008] -[sql-server-2005] -[sybase] -[jpql]
```

is there a more efficient way of finding questions that have been mistagged with a given ambiguous tag?

I'm envisaging something that looks at all the questions tagged with [case-when](/questions/tagged/case-when), evaluates how similar each question is with each other question, and manages to work out that there's there's two groups of questions, where questions within a group are similar to each other but questions in one group are fairly different to questions in the other group.

---

I am trying to retag questions where `case-when` was used but it should have been `switch-statement`. Also, I wouldn't envisage the tool doing the retagging, just provide me with a list of questions that probably should be retagged.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow that last paragraph. Are you trying to retag all `case-when` questions?

Comment: @Asad Just the questions were [tag:case-when] was used but it should have been [tag:switch-statement]. Also, I wouldn't envisage the tool doing the retagging, just provide me with a list of questions that *probably* should be retagged.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a more efficient way of finding questions that have been mistagged with a given ambiguous tag?

data.se can be used to search for question that only include a specific tag:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/364341/filter-questions-by-a-single-tag

> I am trying to retag questions where case-when was used but it should have been switch-statement

data.se can be used to search the accepted answer text and compare it to the tag:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/364342/find-questions-with-one-tag-and-specific-answer-text